# What is the LPTSTR equivalent of _strnicmp in windows?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, api

Is there a LPTSTR equivalent of _strnicmp which takes in 2 LPTSTR strings, and number of TCHARs to compare until?

using the c winapi btw

Comment: The MSDN documentation lists all the variants for each string function in the C API. You can look them up yourself with ease.

Comment: Haven't you heard?  The diskette drive on the last known machine running Windows 98 died last week.  Hurray, no more TCHAR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is `_tcsncicmp`, see [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chd90w8e.aspx).

Comment: Hey, my VSC++ says that _tcsncicmp takes in a const char * even when I have UNICODE and _UNICODE defined before #include <windows.h>, why is that?

Comment: No idea. According to the documentation, it maps to `_wcsnicmp` when `_UNICODE` is defined. Are you including everything in the right order, and did you configure your project settings correctly?

Comment: What about the case sensitive compare version, is it _tcsnccmp?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eywx8zcx.aspx

Comment: Yes. The extra `c` in the `_t`-versions means "compare by character, not byte"; it's the opposite of the extra `b` in the `_mb`-versions.